# Converting a group of functions into a class, issues with naming and objects

Tags: python, class

I have a bunch of functions to evaluate my configuration file. (adding some of those below)

```
class Struct:
    """Returns an callable structure"""
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)   

def read_config(filename):
    """Reads a config file.
    :param filename: String with path to file name
    :returns dict: Dict structure of config file
    """

    try:
        config_file = open(filename,'r')

        try:
            config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
        except yaml.YAMLError as e:
                print "Error in configuration file:", e
                sys.exit(e.errno)
        finally:
            config_file.close()
    except ( IOError, OSError ) as e:
        print "{0}: Error while openining configuration: {2}".format(__name__,
                e.errno, e.strerror)
        sys.exit(e.errno)

    c = Struct(**config)

    return c

def get_depot_param(depot,param):
    """Reads the param from configuration file. If does not exist returns the default.
    :param depot: The depot to be read from config file
    :retuns string: String with param
    """
    try:
        p = cfg.depots[depot][param]
    except ( TypeError, KeyError) as e:
        try:
            # We failed to get the project regex. Fetching default.
            p = getattr(cfg, param)
        except KeyError as e:
            # Default not defined
                print "Error in configuration file: {0}: No default {1} defined. Please add a {1} entry on conf file".format(exc, param)
                sys.exit(e.errno)

    return p
```

The conf file read is a yaml and has a format like this:

```
loglevel: INFO
username: root
password: globalsecret
destdir: /dsk/bkpdir/

# Configurations here overwrites the defaults. The valid ones are:
# username, password, destdir
depots:
    server1:
        password: secret

    server2:
        username: root

    server3:

    server4:
        destdir: /disk2/bkp/
```

The idea is to be able to use a "global" configuration, if the configuration isn't set inside the depot. Because that I have created `get_depot_param` that will try to read the depot param (as `username`, `password`, `dstdir`, and others). If it do not find on depot, grab from global.

I often call these functions like this:

```
# To "initialize" the configurator descriptor
config_filename='backup.cfg'
cfg=read_config(config_filename)

# Calling one attribute from server2 (here I expect receive /dsk/bkpdir/)
get_depot_param('server2','destdir') 

# Calling one attribute from server4 (here I expect receive /disk2/bkp)
get_depot_param('server4','destdir')
```

But I started to convert those functions to a class something like:

```
import errno
import yaml
import sys


class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries): 
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

class Config:
    def __init__(self, filename="backup.cfg"):
        try:
            fd = open(filename,'r')

            try:
                yamlcfg = yaml.safe_load(fd)
            except yaml.YAMLError as e:
                    sys.exit(e.errno)
            finally:
                fd.close()
        except ( IOError, OSError ) as e:
            sys.exit(e.errno)

        self.cfg = Struct(**yamlcfg)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return self.cfg.__getattribute__(name)


    def depot_param(self,depot,param):
        try:
            self.depot_param = self.cfg.depots[depot][param]
        except ( TypeError, KeyError) as e:
            try:
                self.depot_param = getattr(self.cfg, param)
            except KeyError as e:
                    sys.exit(e.errno)

        return self.depot_param

    def project_param(self,project,param):
        try:
            self.project_param = self.cfg.projects[project][param]
        except ( TypeError, KeyError) as e:
            try:
                self.project_param = getattr(self.cfg, param)
            except KeyError as e:
                sys.exit(e.errno)

        return self.project_param



###################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read config file to cfg
    config = Config()

    #print config.loglevel
    #print config.depot_param('server1','destdir')
    #print config.depot_param('server2','destdir')
    #print config.depot_param('server3','password')
```

Running this code I receive:

```
# python backup.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backup.py", line 59, in <module>
    print config.loglevel
AttributeError: Config instance has no attribute 'loglevel'
```

Comment: I noticed if I `print cfg.cfg.loglevel`, gives me the correct output. Awful naming, thinking in how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to access custom attributes inside a class and to avoid the 'awful naming' given by yours, we are going to need to use the **getattribute**(self, name) to get full control of the new class.

An example;

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myItems = {'loglevel':'INFO'}

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            # get the class attributes as "priority", before anything else.
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except AttributeError:
            # attribute was not found, try to get it from our list.
            return self.myItems.get(name)
```

This would enable us to do,

```
config = Config()
print config.loglevel # output is INFO.
```

However, it will return None on an attribute that does not exist, you can turn back the exception by checking if our dictionary contains it, and if not throwing it again.

I couldn't find any issues with depot_param returning the TypeError as of yet.

EDIT:
No issues in depot_param, tested it within my workspace. However a quicker solution for your issue with getting attributes quickly in a nicer way;

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    try:
        # call superclass for attribute, they come in as priority.
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    except AttributeError:
        # call cfg for attribute, this would be like 'self.cfg.cfg.loglevel'
        # but instead, 'self.cfg.loglevel'
        return self.cfg.__getattribute__(name)
```

Comment: In [26]: config.__getattribute__('loglevel') 
Out[26]: 'INFO'

But:

print config.loglevel
AttributeError: Config instance has no attribute 'loglevel'

Comment: Edited the initial answer with the code that I just tested, this works perfectly fine and I was able to 'cfg.loglevel' and get 'INFO' as response. Plus, there is no issue with depot_param, except that it doesn't really return anything. But I couldn't get the TypeError that you were getting.

Comment: about depot_param: I noticed if I ran the command twice, it fails. 

`In [2]: config.depot_param('server4','destdir')`
`Out[2]: '/disk2/bkp/'`

`In [3]: config.depot_param('server4','destdir')`
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)`
`...`
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

This is just weird to me. Can't figure out why.

Comment: @Lin The instance method `depot_param` and the attribute `self.depot_param` have the same name. In other words, in your method `depot_param` you are redefining the method when you do `self.depot_param = [...]`. So, when you go to try to call the method, you are actually trying to call the string that was assigned to `self.depot_param`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Indeed. I didn't noticed that. Thank you very much.